# Docker Tomcat with ActiveMQ linked

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, activemq-classic

I need a docker container with Tomcat and ActiveMQ. I managed to do this with the usage of supervisord, and the container is working perfectly and all. But then I thought that the concept is bad, since I don`t want to lose my activeMQ messages when I deploy a new war in Tomcat. 
So I made 2 containers and linked them, one for activemq and one for tomcat. 
I can see that tomcat is linked to activemq, but the deployed war in tomcat does nothing with activeMQ.

My question is: any tips how can I check why aren't they communicating, even if the containers are linked, environments created and so on?

Also if someone could link a git hub repo where somebody is using tomcat with activemq linked from 2 different containers?

Also if some of you knows a good practice bloog, related to usage of activemq in docker, I am worried about the lost messages when recreating a container.

From my point of view a docker container is something which should be able to be build from an image in the exact same state. With active MQ this is a bit more tricky, I don't know exactly where does activemq save on the disk the messages, and if a shared volume will fix the persistence problem with docker. On the other hand you don`t redeploy that often a container with activemq, but what if it will happen, host restart (-> destroying all containers).. what are the safety measures?

Comment: you can `docker exec container_id bash` in your 2 containers, and debug like you would do on any Linux, also use `docker logs` and `docker events`

Comment: I am doing that, in tomcat I have the error  "Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616", where tomcat is trying to connect. I checked with printenv and the AMQ_ENV related ports/ips are set (bacause of the link), still the connection is not working.